# Excel web queries - how do I add the data I get to a running list rather than just updating the latest number?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, screen-scraping

I have a web query that pulls data from a website. Each day the website publishes an updated value for an index. And I can pull that value into my spreadsheet. But I'd like to make a running list of the values, with a date column and a second column with the value for that date.  How can I do this?  Right now, the query just over-writes the previous data whenever it's updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every day / update;
Insert a new row below your current values;
then copy the VALUES to that new row (Paste > Special > Values).

You will have a growing list of values, a set of values per update you've done.

If you want VBA code for it: Enable the developer tab in options, then record it. To run it can then be bound either a button or a keystroke (shortcut).

Comment: I ended up doing something like this.  Some other sites have some complex code to do this, but I decided to go with this simpler method.

Comment: I tend to use the simplest possible solution to similar things. It might often be possible to create more "elegant" solutions, but that might also be a hindrance for other things; e.g. speedwise.